Websocket from ESP32 to Python to slow
I am working on a project where I have Python server that's connected to an esp32 cam (AI Thinker) via a websocket.
The ESP32 cam constantly takes frames and sends them to the server, where they are being streamed to the user.
Server code:
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import uvicorn
import asyncio


app = FastAPI()
queue = asyncio.Queue()


async def stream():
    while True:
        img_bytes = await queue.get()

        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img_bytes + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.get("/")
async def root():       
    return StreamingResponse(
        stream(), media_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame"
    )

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    while True:
        res = await websocket.receive()
        if "bytes" not in res.keys():
            continue
    
        await queue.put(res["bytes"])

        print(f"updated queue, queue size is {queue.qsize()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=30000)

client code
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "esp_websocket_client.h"

#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM 32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM 0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM 26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM 27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM 35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM 34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM 39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM 36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM 21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM 19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM 18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM 5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM 25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM 23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM 22

const char *ssid = "usrname";
const char *password = "password";

esp_websocket_client_handle_t client;

void initSerialMonitor() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

    Serial.println("Serial monitor initied");
}

void initWiFi() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.printf("\nWifi initied ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void initCamera() {
  camera_config_t config;
  
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY;
  config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 1;

  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Camera initied");
}


static void websocket_event_handler(void *handler_args, esp_event_base_t base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data)
{
    esp_websocket_event_data_t *data = (esp_websocket_event_data_t *)event_data;
    switch (event_id) {
    case WEBSOCKET_EVENT_CONNECTED:
        Serial.println("Websocket connected");
        break;
    case WEBSOCKET_EVENT_DATA:
        Serial.print("Websocket got data: ");
        Serial.println((char *)data->data_ptr);
        break;
    }
}


void initWebsocket() {
  esp_websocket_client_config_t websocket_cfg = {};
  websocket_cfg.uri = "ws://172.20.10.2:30000/ws";
  client = esp_websocket_client_init(&websocket_cfg);
  esp_websocket_register_events(client, WEBSOCKET_EVENT_ANY, websocket_event_handler, (void *)client);

  esp_websocket_client_start(client);
}

void setup() {
  initSerialMonitor();
  initCamera();
  initWiFi();
  initWebsocket();

  Serial.println("Finish setup");
}

void loop() {
    camera_fb_t *pic = esp_camera_fb_get();
    esp_websocket_client_send(client, (char*)pic->buf, pic->len, portMAX_DELAY);
    Serial.printf("got picture with len %d\n", pic->len);
    esp_camera_fb_return(pic);
    delay(10);
}

Everything works fine, but the function esp_websocket_client_send is way too slow and can take up to a second.
How can I make the websocket faster, and are they even right for this use case?

JPEG over websocket is simply said not the fastest way to stream a video.

@KlausD. what should I change?, should I change the format? or use other communication technology like UDP sockets?
